# How do I parse and save all the classes with their properties from an RDF file using Jena API in Java?

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I have a project where I need to parse an RDF file and record all the data on which I will have to search for specific data afterwards. I searched the web and all I could find was how to query the said RDF file but I want to parse it and save all the classes in objects.

This is how a class looks in my file:

```
<BFO rdf:about="BFO:0000007">
    <rdfs:label>process</rdfs:label>  
    <Definition>  
        <rdf:Description>  
            <def>A process is an entity that exists in time by occurring or happening, has temporal parts and always involves and depends on some entity during the time it occurs.</def>  
        </rdf:Description>  
    </Definition>  
    <is_a rdf:resource="EFO:0000001"/>  
</BFO>
```

Update:

yea all u said worked, thank you very much for that but one last question:) the namespaces i have are:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
xmlns="http://www.ebi.ac.uk/efo/">
</rdf>
```

My question is for the

```
        <Definition>
        <rdf:Description>
        <def>smth here</def>
        </rdf:Description>
    </Definition>  


i couldn't find a way to get the def tag, any idea how i can access it? sry to bother again:)
```

Comment: Reading RDF files is basic Jena stuff. Have you looked at the related questions here or the [Jena tutorial for the RDF API](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html)? By "save the classes in objects", do you mean *use in-memory storage*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jena uses the `Model` object to store RDF that has been parsed from an external source, such as a file or web URL. Depending on your project's needs, and the size of the data, you have a basic choice of whether to read the file into a memory `Model`, or a persistent `Model`. Memory is generally faster to access, but of course once your program exits the contents of the memory model are lost (well, unless you write them to a file again).

You should read the [Jena tutorials](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/) to get a better understanding of the processes involved, but reading a file into a Jena memory model is very easy:

```
String source = ".. your file location ..";
Model m = FileManager.get().loadModel( source, "RDF/XML" );
```

If a persistent model would better suit your project, the best choice [is Jena TDB](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/index.html). Again, it's very easy to get a model that you can begin querying.

You also asked:

> and save all the classes in objects

I'm not quite sure what you mean here. Possibly you're thinking of some sort of ORM tool, similar to ActiveRecord? There's nothing built-in to Jena to do that, though there have been various other projects that have looked at doing something like an ORM layer. I'm not sure which of them is currently active though. But you don't need an ORM to access the properties of your resources, you can just use the Jena API:

```
String namespace = ".. your namespace here ..";
Resource bfo = m.getResource( namespace + "BFO:0000007" );
Property definition = m.getProperty( namespace + "Definition" );
RDFNode def = bfo.getProperty( definition ).getObject();
```

**Updated**

OK, in response to the comments: if you don't know which properties to expect on a resource, you can list them:

```
String namespace = ".. your namespace here ..";
Resource bfo = m.getResource( namespace + "BFO:0000007" );
for (StmtIterator i = bfo.listProperties(); i.hasNext(); ) {
  Statement smt = i.next();
  System.out.println( "Resource " + stmt.getSubject().getURI() + 
                      " has property " + stmt.getPredicate().getURI() +
                      " with value " + stmt.getObject() );
}
```

This is just a very simple loop, you will want to do something much more useful, but hopefully that shows you that you can still process the resources in the model without knowing their properties in advance. Of course, at some point in your code you will have to connect a particular property to whatever your application wants to do with that particular value of the resource. So somewhere your code will have to have some knowledge of which properties to expect.

Re-reading your comment, I notice you refer to "concepts in an ontology" (even though there are no classes in the RDF fragment you quoted in the question). You might find the capabilities of the [Jena ontology API](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/index.html) useful, which can list the ontology classes in a model, the properties that have been defined, etc.

Comment: thank you for the respons ian. im quite bad with expressing what i want:).My problem is that my concepts in the rdf ontology have different properties from one-another so my problem was how can use an iterator to go through all the concepts in the ontology and though all their properties without using(m.getProperty( namespace + "Definition" );) the Definition word as some may not have definition but might have say Propertyx, if it makes sence....Anyways thank you again for taking your time to help me. Much appreciated